# Is there an equivalent to source which allows me to have a batch script alter environment variables of the parent bash process?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, cmd.exe

My situation is this: I use python with conda on a windows machine, and work mostly in cygwin when on the command line. Now conda allows for different python environments, similar to virtualenv, but it only ships with an activation.bat script for switching the environments. Normally I would do something like `source activate env`, but that obviously doesn't work with a non-bash script. My workaround looks like this:

```
cmd /C "activate $1 & bash"
```

Which works fine but is a little unsatisfying because it feels like a workaround. Is there a way to import the environment variables of a child process into the parent process?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.  Your use of "&" in a `cmd` call is about as close as you could get.  You might be able to make it look a little cleaner using [`call`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490873.aspx) for the "activate.bat" script.

Because `call` does not stop the "parent" batch-program, that is closer to the shell "source" which was requested.  I use this in batch-files which build up environment variables before using them later in the script.

However, it is unclear which "parent" process you are referring to in

```
cmd /C "activate $1 & bash"
```

since you report that you are propagating variables from `activate.bat` into the subsequent `bash` command (unless you mean the parent of `cmd`).

Comment: Yes I mean the parent of `cmd` (the cygwin bash shell)

Answer (score 0):

In `cmd`, variables are leaked to the environment by default. You have to surround your commands by `setlocal`-`endlocal` to explicitly avoid this. Therefore, you may use the approach suggested by [Thomas Dickey](https://superuser.com/users/441480/thomas-dickey) to put your environment variables in a `.bat` file and `call` that first.

We usually do this on Windows machines, by providing a `setenv.bat` script that we run first on the command prompt before invoking other scripts.

Edit: to set an environment for a parent process we sometimes do the following. Simply have a file of key-value-pairs describing the environment:

```
envkey1=envval1
envkey2=envval2
```

and read that in the parent process and adjust the environment that way.

My Python-fu is not that great, but in Perl you would do something like

```
open(my $f, '<', 'env.txt');
while (<$f>) {
  chomp;
  my ($k, $v) = split(m/=/, $_, 2); # assumes '=' as separator
  $ENV{$k} = $v; # updates the current environment
}
close($f);
```

Comment: Yes but they are not leaked to the parent process, which is a cygwin bash shell in this case.